# Add static files like resources in Java eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have couple .c files in my java project. How to achieve in Eclipse to project see this .c files like resources ?

Comment: Could you clarify how you expect "like resources" to look like? I don't see the problem, if the .c-files are inside the project, they ARE already resources (files) in Eclipse's sense. It seems you are expected something particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an additional src folder that points to the file system folder which contains those files.

Or, inside your src folder, create a new file/folder which is a link to the external file/folder.

Answer (score 1):

if it is maven project  then simplyput all c file in `/resource/c/`

if it is simple java project , put all C file in a different package.

if it is a web project put it in `WEB-INF/C/`

Answer (score 1):

Are your .c files C programs?.

You can install c/c++ eclipse plugin named CDT to view the source.

[CDT site.](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/)